# Fix last-but-one space-separated words to move files

Tags: batch-file

I try to move files making with a script their respective folders.
Example of desidered and wrong output

[image]

To set a substring I use

```
for %%I in (*.cbr) do (

   set "file=%%I"
   for %%J in ("!file: =\!") do set "folder=!file: %%~nxJ=!"
```

For example if I have this filenames

```
the punisher one.cbr
the punisher two.cbr
```

the folder name will be `the punisher`

Problem is when I try to move with another example. If I have 3 files

```
the punisher beta.cbr
the punisher beta new.cbr
the punisher past.cbr
```

and I use this command to make directories

```
mkdir "!folder!" 2>NUL
   move /Y "!file!" "!folder!"
```

But with this example is where I fail and I get unwanted outcome because it creates 3 folders instead of only one (it wrongly also move all files when should be move only 2 files in one folder)

Where is the mistake? I don't understand if is here

```
for %%J in ("!file: =\!") do set "folder=!file: %%~nxJ=!"
```

or here

```
mkdir "!folder!" 2>NUL
       move /Y "!file!" "!folder!"
```

Entire code example is

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%I in (*.pdf) do (

   set "file=%%I"
   for %%J in ("!file: =\!") do set "folder=!file: %%~nxJ=!"

   mkdir "!folder!" 2>NUL
   move /Y "!file!" "!folder!"
   echo "!file!" moved to "!folder!"

)
```